# avcodec_decode_audio4 was deprecated, how can i Decode the audio frame of size avpkt->size from avpkt->data into frame

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

avcodec_decode_audio4 was deprecated, how can i Decode the audio frame of size avpkt->size from avpkt->data into frame. I am now migrating ffmpeg from v2.5 to 4.1 in my project.

Comment: Check latest examples: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/decode_audio_8c-example.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I get the answer, in the new version, we can get pkt->size directly.